# Joint entropy of a bivariate Gamma probability density function

Tags: gamma-distribution, joint-distribution, entropy, bivariate

In Nadarajah and Kotz, 2009 (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-39/issue-1/Four-Bivariate-Distributions-with-Gamma-Type-Marginals/10.1216/RMJ-2009-39-1-231.full), they present (Corollary 1) a bivariate Gamma distribution which marginals are Gamma type:
$$ f(x,y) = C (xy)^{c-1} \left(  \dfrac{x}{\mu_1} + \dfrac{y}{\mu_2}  \right)^{a-2c} \Gamma  \left(  2c-a, \dfrac{x}{\mu_1} + \dfrac{y}{\mu_2}   \right) $$
where $C = \dfrac{1}{(\mu_1 \mu_1)^c \Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c)}$ and $b=1$ and $\Gamma(a,x) = \int_x^{+\infty} t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt $ is the complementary incomplete Gamma function.
The marginals $X,Y$ are Gamma distributed with shape parameters $a$ and scale parameters $1/\mu_1$ and $1/\mu_2$. My question is what is the expression of the joint entropy:
$$ H(X,Y) = - \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x,y)\log(f(x,y)) dx dy .$$

Comment: Because [there are many such distributions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089396590500337X), please clarify which one you have in mind or else change your post to characterize the problem that is leading you to consider bivariate gammas.

Comment: Re your edits: part of the concept of a bivariate "X" distribution is that both marginals are univariate distributions of type "X." The problem is that there is generally no unique or natural way to parameterize a family of *associations* between then.  Thus, emphasizing that you want the marginals to be Gamma doesn't bring us any closer to understanding what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joint entropy is an integral that is difficult to calculate even from wolfram alpha. But by fixing the values ​​of $a,b,\mu_1,\mu_2$ is possible to get numerical value by using symbolic integration by wolfram alpha. So the answer is: it is not yet possible to get a symbolic expression of the integral but by fixing the parameters one can get the numerical value of the integral.